# get regex between fourth and fifth symbol even if it is empty

Tags: regex

I got a whole list of those lines:

```
randomtext1', 'somethingelsehere', 'randomtext2', 'link-to-something', 'random-date', 'randomdate2', 'randomname'),
```

and I want to be able to extract one of those entrys.

```
somethingelsehere, link-to-something, ...
```

So I tried using http://regexr.com/ to get the regexcode that works for this, but i can't figure it out.

My thought was that I could simply "mark" the things I want by saying ignore the first, second and third `'` then start at the fourth `'` until the fifth `'` and ignore the sixth to thirteenth again. That should give me `randomtext2`.

The problem is, that sometimes there is nothing in between the `''`, but I want to get that aswell The `''` should be included in this so that I would get `'randomtext2'` instead of `randomtext2`.

I tried to understand regex, but it really is extremly complex and pretty hard to understand for me so help would be really appreciated :)

xF4m3

Edit1: Example lines:
line 1: 3d-furnaces', '', 'spAnser', 'minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1288346-3d-furnace-v1-4', '2015-09-27 13:41:50', '2015-09-27 13:41:50', '3D Furnaces'),
line 2: 4space', 'No idee what to put here, but it sometimes is there', '4spaceTeam', '4space.mods.center/#download', '2015-09-27 15:45:27', '2015-09-27 15:45:27', '4Space'),

I want to extract 'spAnser' and 'minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1288346-3d-furnace-v1-4' from the first line and '4spaceTeam' and 'mods.center/#download' from the second line.

See http://pastebin.com/7tGJB7kh for a better list

I Used regexr.com aswell as regex101.com I need to extract the 3rd and fourth group
"(.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?), (.*?), (.*?)," that is my regex code to mark all groups, i do not know how i can exclude group 1-3 and 5-8. Examples can be found on pastebin.

Comment: Can you provide the regex you tried and failed, the regex flavor/tool, real input samples and the actual fields you need to extract?

Comment: "(.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*?), (.*?), (.*?),"
that is my regex code to mark all groups, i do not know how i can exclude group 1-3 and 5-8 

an example would be here:
http://pastebin.com/7tGJB7kh

Comment: I Used http://regexr.com/ aswell as https://www.regex101.com/ 
I need to extract the 3rd and fourth group

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what you tried, instead of burying it (badly formatted) inside a comment.

Comment: This is not a problem that should be solved with regular expressions.

Comment: How to "exclude group 1-3 and 5-8": Change them from capturing groups `(xxx)` to non-capturing groups [`(?:xxx)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group).

Comment: I leave my [regex approach](https://regex101.com/r/jT6cU5/1) as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
(?m)^.*?' *, *'.*?' *, *('.*?') *, *('.*?')
```

See [regex101.com demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/bZ4zA7/1) using the *exact* data from your [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/7tGJB7kh).

Comment: Thanks, that really helped, not what I had in mind, but totally worked like I had hoped it to! Also for everyone who doesn't understand this, just paste this regex into https://www.regex101.com/ , it explains what the diffrent symbloes do.

Comment: @xF4m3 No need to paste into regex101. Just click the "demo" link I provided, and it'll be pre-filled, with regex *and* your test data.